# Finding a file using Putty and FTP

Tags: html, ftp, putty

what I want to do is very simple. I want  to edit a html file of a webpage I have on a standard Centos server. I can access it just fine, and Apache is set to look in /var/www/sitename. Here is my problem:

The url of the page I want to edit is like so: http://www.yoursite/page1

I think that somewhere in /var/www/sitename, there should be a file called page1.html. But there isn't. I've ran search functions in FileZilla and Putty (using 
find /var/www/yoursite/ -exec grep -l "jeyword-from-page-1" {} \;

It all seems very simple but I can't find the file I am supposed to edit. Where should I look for it? Any ideas or tips are greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time in advance!

**EDIT:**

Thank you all for the replies. Here is what I found in my htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(engine|inc|info|install|make|module|profile|test|po|sh|.*sql|theme|tpl(\.php)?|xtmpl|svn-base)$|^(code-style\.pl|Entries.*|Repository|Root|Tag|Template|all-wcprops|entries|format)$">
  Order allow,deny
</FilesMatch>

# Set the default handler.
DirectoryIndex index.php



  # If your site is running in a VirtualDocumentRoot at http://example.com/,
  # uncomment the following line:
  RewriteBase /

  # Rewrite URLs of the form 'x' to the form 'index.php?q=x'.
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

These are the ones that look suspicious to me, nothing out of the ordinary with the other lines. Could this be it?

EDIT2: I just found these lines in my index.php file:

```
/**
 * @file
 * The PHP page that serves all page requests on a Drupal installation.
 *
 * The routines here dispatch control to the appropriate handler, which then
 * prints the appropriate page.
 *
 * All Drupal code is released under the GNU General Public License.
 * See COPYRIGHT.txt and LICENSE.txt.
 */
```

Comment: check that .htaccess isn't doing some trickery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you need grep. Use name like this: find /path/to/site -name "filename".

Comment: The thing is, I wanted to search inside the files for something that is displayed in yoursite/page1 Like "apples" per example. Then, even if it wasn't a standard .html, but some other file, I could still find it. But no such luck.

Comment: In your .htacess file it looks like you are using a cms. I'm afraid you need to look into the cms and not in the files.

Answer (score 1):

Check your serverblock/virtualhost configurations for where the files reside

This should be somewhere in `/etc/apache2/` or `/etc/httpd/` for Apache and `/etc/nginx/` or `/opt/local/nginx/` for Nginx

Comment: Hello Koen, thanks for your answer. So from /etc/httpd/ I opened httpd.conf. Is "Document root" the directory I'm looking for? because it oints to var/www/html which is an empty directory, yet the pages show just fine, so it must be somewhere else. What do you think?

Comment: try grepping for `VirtualHost` in `/etc/httpd/`: `grep -r 'VirtualHost' /etc/httpd` and see if there's another location somewhere. Otherwise try to look for hidden files in `/var/www/html`

Comment: Hi, the grep resulted in results only from /etc/httpd/conf/ . Couldn't find any other directory. Look for hidden files how? Its already a 777, anything else I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there has to be a page called that name. .htaccess file might override the default route of such request and it's very possible that your page has a script, that loads file with completely different filename to display content. (I'm sorry, if I assumed incorrectly, that you don't exactly understand what that webpage on your webserver does)

Comment: I posted some of my htaccess above, could you take a look please? If we can get the file from which the script loads from the above it would be great. Well, the page is a very simple html page - the source code is standard and it just has some About Me info and a bunch of pictures.

Comment: ok I thought you were using some kind of premade CMS system, that you haven't programmed yourself. Well I don't understand how drupal framework works and also I don't know if you need to modify the HTML file, maybe you just need to modify the content from within admin panel of Drupal? If you absolutely need to change for example the template of the page(not the content of the page), you should either study how Drupal works, or if you don't understand php, you should get someone who understands php to do it for you